# How to use XmlPullParser with UTF-8?

Tags: android, xml, utf-8, android-xml, android-xmlpullparser

I'm trying to decode a XML using XmlPullParser with UTF-8 but something is going wrong because when a string is "dirección" I am getting "direcci& #xf3;n" (without spaces between & and #).

I did this:

```
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(input, "UTF-8");
```

Also I tried with `parser.setInput(input, "utf-8");` but same problem

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the difference in your strings? Aren't they same?

Comment: There is having the simplest example for XMLPullParser with UTF-8 in this Url which also i followed :http://www.javatpoint.com/android-XMLPullParser-tutorial

Comment: waqaslam i edited my question

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with UTF-8 specifically. I think this is a problem with the parser turning special characters into HTML entities. If there were a charset problem, I would expect to see some garbled text or ? symbols. Have you tried something like: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(xml); (Apache Commons)